# Authentication over REST

Tags: python, django, angularjs, django-rest-framework, restangular

***Update 3***: The REST API Permissions: when defining the viewset associate the proper permission class...

```
class TopSecretViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = myModels.TopSecret.objects.all()
    serializer_class = mySerializers.TopSecretSerializer
    permission_classes = (myAuth.MyIsAuthenticated,)
```

***Update 2***: The REST Authentication

**Edit**: *return a Permissions Object with the user*

Settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'app.authentication.MyAuthentication',
    )
```

authentication.py

```
class MyIsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to authenticated, if it is AnnoymousUser we 
    don't allow access.  There will be more code here - but this is 
    good for the example
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user and isinstance(request.user, myModels.User):
            return True
        return False


######################################################
# TODO: return the apropiate permissions
######################################################    
class MyAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        cookies = request.COOKIES
        if 'user' in cookies:
            userCookie = request.COOKIES['user']
            userJson = base64.b64decode(userCookie)
            userDict = json.loads(userJson)
            userId = userDict['user_id']

            if not userId:
                return None

            try:
                user =myModels.User.objects.get(user_id=userId)
            except myModels.User.DoesNotExist:
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')

            return (user, MyIsAuthenticated)
        return None
```

***Update***: Working the solution

The django restframework viewset:

**Edit**: *added a base64 encode cookie of the user object (which is being returned in the JSON payload as well*

```
#####################################################################
# handles two REST APIs GET/list users (through the mixin and) in 
#     accordance to the rules of the UserLoginSerializer
#     the POST/create - and while I don't like handling this in the
#     create method, this is the post of the login credentials
#####################################################################
class UserViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = myModels.User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = mySerializers.UserLoginSerializer

    def set_cookie(response, key, value, days_expire=7, host=''):
        if days_expire is None:
            max_age = 1 * 24 * 60 * 60  #1 day
        else:
            max_age = days_expire * 24 * 60 * 60
        expires = datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=max_age),"%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S GMT")

        host = host.split(':')[0]

        response.set_cookie(key, value, max_age=max_age, expires=expires, domain=host)
        return response

    def create(self, request):
        login_email = request.DATA['email']
        login_password = request.DATA['password']
        login_password = login_password
        user = myModels.User.objects.get(email=login_email)

        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        md5.update(login_password)
        login_password_md5 = unicode(md5.hexdigest())

        if (user and login_password_md5 == user.password):

            user.last_login = datetime.now()
            user.save()

            role = 4 #verfied user
            responseData = {
                    'user_id': user.user_id
                    , 'firstName': user.firstname
                    , 'lastName': user.lastname
                    , 'email': login_email
                    , 'role': role
            }

            return  set_cookie(
                Response(responseData)
                , 'user'
                , base64.b64encode(json.dumps(responseData, ensure_ascii=False))
                , days_expire=1
                , host = request.META['HTTP_HOST'])

        else:
            role  = 1 #anonymous
            return Response({'email': login_email, 'role': role, 'message': 'Unknown Email or Incorrect Password'
                , 'user_id':  -1, 'first_name': '' , 'last_name': ''})
```

### Original Post

***Edit***: *I am hooking this up to a PHP legacy application to run side by side until I can completely port to Python over the next year or so.  Therefore the attraction of the built in Django Authentication is not as appealing*

I have a single  page web app, that shows a bunch of *teaser* content.  If you click on the content you get prompted to log in. I use a div overlay-ed on the screen to display the log in form, and I want to submit the data on this form to the server for authentication.

Our site currently runs over HTTPS, so I am thinking a simple solution is best for now.

Question 1: The Log In service: I was thinking about performing the log in over a POST REST request, but I am not sure this is the right approach - or really - if there is a better approach.

Question 2: Using Django-Rest-Framework i need to coordinate the Authentication and the Log In service.  I was thinking that I would create a custom Authentication that would read a cookie and identify the proper user and permissions.  Does this seem like a reasonable solution?

Question 3: The Cookie?  Where should I write the cookie?  Should I embed it in the response from the server as part of the Log In service, OR should I write it on the js/client side upon a successful log in.  I think the former is the probably the better method, and can allow me to en[de]crypt the cookie in the future having all of the code in a single place (the server).  Does anybody think that writing the cookie in the javascript side upon a successful log in is better?

My Client Stack: AngularJs, RESTangular (it picks up cookies nicely), and other less interesting pieces

My Server Stack: Python 2.7, Django 1.5, Django-Rest-Framework

Always - thanking you in advance!

Comment: Instead of manually creating user, use django built-in features: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#creating-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered in the original post step by step as I was uncovering the solution.  Essentially the steps are

1. Create a rest service to perform the  authentication.  In using the django rest framework, I inherited from GenericViewet and overrode the create method to handle the POST.  I returned JSON to the UI i the response paylod representing the authenticated user, and I also dumped a cookie with that same object.  The thought is the return payload is better plugged into my angularjs front end, for those controllers waiting for the return response. The cookie can be read when the application starts  up for return visitors, plus it is passed on the REST requests.
2. Create your own Authentication class and plug it into the REST framework (in settings).  In my case I read the cookie and find the user in the DB.If you want to be able to associate permissions on certain REST Apis, then you need to create  your own permissions class (small and simple).  In my example above, I only check the instantiated user class is an instance of my User class - but ultimately I will check individual permissions.
3. add the permissions to the appopriate viewsets

Answer (score 0):

A REST api does not mean you have to do everything using rest.

I would suggest using a REST interface for data which you are using and manipulating, and a custom handler for authentication.

This way, you can use the built-in django authentication, and still use your rest api for the data.  No need to re-invent what you don't have to!

Comment: agreed - and that is my fall back.  AT this point it is an intellectual curiosity